# reverse highcharts heatmap legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/egk1xq2L/11) of a Highcharts heat map. Notice that the numbers in the legend on the right-hand side increase from bottom to top. By default they increase from top to bottom, but I changed this with

```
colorAxis: {
    reversed: false
}
```

However, I now have the problem that the colors on the legend don't match the colors in the heatmap itself. For example, the legend indicates that red colors are the lowest values, but the heat map uses red for the highest values.

The most relevant code in the demo is:

```
colorAxis: {
    reversed: false,
    min: 0,
    stops: [
        [0, '#00FF00'],
        [0.5, '#FF8000'],
        [1, '#FF0040']
    ]
},

legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 320,

    // I tried setting this to true and false but neither fix my problem
    // reversed: true
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fixed in the master branch.

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egk1xq2L/12/

Answer (score 7):

You need to modify what is called the `colorAxis`. It has default properties listed here for [reversed](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.reversed). So for this example link you provided you need to set:

```
colorAxis: {
    reversed: false,
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
},
```

It is different than the `legend` properties which for a `colorAxis` is just handling the location/alignment of the `colorAxis` item. To modify what the `colorAxis` does you have to edit the [`colorAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis) properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried out your solution but now I have a different problem. I've updated my question with a demo that illustrates my new problem. If you could have any further suggestions they'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Dónal This is a known issue it appears. You also will need to flip your color axis `stops` to be the opposite of what they are now.

Comment: flipping the stops doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, putting the reversed attribute within the coloraxis element.